# Migrating the deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, blazor, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 Blazor helper library which has been referencing `HttpContext` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (2.2.0)` nuget. However, this nuget is now flagged as *deprecated* by Microsoft, thus the Visual Studio Nuget manager shows me warnings for this package reference.

But my .Net7 Blazor app is using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web (7.0.5)` and the root razor page `_Host.cshtml` exposes the `HttpContext` property, which I need to pass to a helper method in the above mentioned project.

What am I missing here? If I Browse my way to the `HttpContext` definition from `_Host.cshtml`, Visual Studio claims it's declared in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (7.0.0.0)`, which is nowhere to be found?

I also have similar issues with other, related packages. What's the correct way to reference these packages, without warnings? Or what other packages am I to use?

Comment: Somebody else has just asked this exact same question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173780/what-replaces-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-abstractions-when-migrating-to-net-7 which was closed as a duplicate!

Comment: Check out the suggested duplicates. In short - remove the link to the nuget and add `FrameworkReference` element. Also check out [this part of docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#support-both-hosting-models)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the `FrameworkReference` to **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** prevents the library from being used from Blazor WASM, so this is not the final answer...

Comment: The way I was able to bypass this depreciation issue is to modify the project file and include the reference to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App".

Reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#only-support-the-blazor-server-hosting-model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#only-support-the-blazor-server-hosting-model)

Comment: That's what was mentioned in the comments above, but it doesn't work for Blazor WebAssembly. That's why we ended up splitting up libraries for WASM/Server.

Comment: @phuzi your link is broken

Comment: @SergioSolorzano That other has since been deleted!

Comment: As suggested by other people, this is not a valid solution for blazor wasm project. I am having the same issue now. 
I noticed that there is a pre-release version for .net 8. 
Options now are: splitting up projects or living with the deprecation. The framework reference cannot be included for blazor wasm

Comment: @Hairydruidy - as mentioned by @GTRocker, how about including a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`? 
At least this works for .NET 7 web apps - perhaps it will work for blazor too?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/ is also marked as deprecated now.    GAAAA.